# protect_from_forgery :secret in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started reading Agile Web Development with Rails, its a very good book!

I have one question:
I store session in database, I want comment out this line in application_controller:

protect_from_forgery :secret => '8fc080370e56e929a2d5afca5540a0f7'

in rails 2.3.8. its different (# See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details), where is this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application controller you should have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

In config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_example_session',
  :secret      => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}

ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
```